# How do I relocate (x, y) jPanel that is already appearing in the GUI

Tags: java, netbeans, location, jpanel

**Navigator:**
jPanel -> jPanelBitPad , 
jButton -> jButtonMode

**Objective:**
When the button has the text 'PRACTICE', it will have the jPanel to appear at location (260, 10). When the button is clicked and the text changes from 'PRACTICE' to 'EXAMPLE', it will have the jPanel to appear at location (150,10) instead.

**Problem:**
The jPanel is not relocating when I clicked the button.

```
if (jButtonMode.getText().equals("PRACTICE")) {
        jButtonMode.setText("EXAMPLE");
        jPanelBitPad.setLocation(150, 10);
    } else if (jButtonMode.getText().equals("EXAMPLE")) {
        jButtonMode.setText("PRACTICE");
        jPanelBitPad.setLocation(260, 10);
    }
```

Comment: what's happening exactly?

Comment: When the program is run, the panel is at (150, 10). When the button is clicked and the text on the button changes from Example to Practice, the panel doesn't relocate to the new position which is (260, 10).

Comment: I would like to have the jpanel to shift accordingly from (150,10) to (260,10) and vice-versa. However, I did not get that. I am not sure what is missing/incorrect with the codes.